# How to rotate a video by 180 degrees using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to cut a short part of a video and rotate it by 180 degrees. I tried

```
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,vflip" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "transpose=1,transpose=1" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "transpose=1,transpose=1,hflip" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "transpose=1,transpose=1,vflip" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 70 -display_rotation 180 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10  -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
```

and some more random combinations. They do not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the metadata: `ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -t 10 passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4`, or maybe `rotate=180`. Modifying the metadata (with `-c copy`) may be better solution since it doesn't re-encode the video.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a very counterintuitive solution:

```
ffmpeg -ss 70 -i GH030258.MP4 -t 10 -vf "rotate=0" -c:a copy  passing_opponent_alarm_084305.mp4
```

Seems I have to rotate the video by 0 degrees to rotate it by 180 degrees! (But if I just omit this rotate=0, the video will NOT be rotated and generated a video upside down ...)